# Additional geographical area on State

Tags: lookup, country-and-state

I'd like to add additional information on the State in Salesforce, for example the macro-area it belongs to, so that it can be used in any report, view, feature that make usage of an Address / State.

It looks like the State object cannot be customized, what is the right approach to handle this in Salesforce? Are there automatic lookups towards custom metadata types, for example??